# phpbb3's slow indexing of new messages

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, phpbb

I try to found solution to improve phpbb3 new message indexing. I have about 10000 messages on my forum, and each new message adds VERY long time (20-30 sec). I've checked mysql_slow.log and found long queries there which is actually adding message into phpbb3's index.

Do someone have or find any ready solutions?

Comment: What version are you on your phpbb3 installation? Also, could you post a sample of the sql logs that you are getting to check if those are from phpbb or not?

Comment: what kind of message indexing have you chosen from the admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let MySQL run for 72+ hours (without being restarted) and then download and run MySQL Tuner:
(as root)

```
cd ~/
wget http://www.mysqltuner.pl/ -O ./mysqltuner.pl
chmod +x ./mysqltuner.pl
./mysqltuner.pl
```

That will give you a good idea of what tweaks you can do to improve performance based upon your actual usage and needs. After you make the tweaks you'll want to restart MySQL and then give it another 48 to 72 hours before you run the tuner again to see if there is any finer tuning you can do.

Comment: you should also check the phpBB forums for large community site tweaks, as far as I can remember from the phpBB 2.x era phpBB is actually not intended for large communities